# How to restrict fields when creating post request in DRF?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am making a POST api using DRF. In that api, I need only few fields(name, size, customer_name, customer_address), but don't require this fields(status, ordered_time) because these fields I want to save these fields in run time as status='open' and ordered_time=DateTimeField.now()

**views.py**

```
class PizzaOrderCustomerView(APIView):   
    def post(self, request):
        orders = request.data.get('orders')
        # Create an article from the above data
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=orders)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            article_saved = serializer.save()
        return Response({"success": "Article '{}' created successfully".format(article_saved.name)})
```

**models.py**

```
class PizzaOrder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SIZE_CHOICE, default='MEDIUM')
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    customer_address = models.TextField()
    ordered_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='open', editable=False)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PizzaOrder
        # fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('status',)
```

But when I try to create an order, it needed status and ordered_time also. But it should save at the time of creating order automatically.
Suggest a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins


class PizzaViewsets(viewsets.ViewSet, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    model = PizzaOrder
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    queryset = model.objects.all(
```

serializer, it is always good practise to mention all fields instead of 
**all**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PizzaOrder
        fields = ('status','ordered_time','name', 'size', 'customer_name', 'customer_address',)
        read_only_fields = ('status','ordered_time',)
```